# Removing duplicate values from a column in SQL

Tags: sql, database, partition

I have two tables `A` (`group_id, id, subject`) and `B` (`id, date`). Below is the joint table of tables A and B on id. I have tried using distinct and partition to remove the duplicates in group_id(field) only, but no luck:

[image]

My code:

```
select 
    a.group_id, a.id, a.subject, b.date 
from
    A a 
inner join
    (select 
         b.*, 
         row_number() over (partition by group_id order by date asc) as seqnum
     from 
         B b) b on a.id = b.id and seqnum = 1
order by
    date desc;
```

I got this error when I ran the code:

> Partitioning can not be used stand-alone in query near 'partition by group_id order by date asc) as seqnum from B' at line 1

This is my expected result:

[image: my expected result:]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your allude to two tables in the question, but only show one.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the earliest date for each row in the table you show.  Your question mentions two tables, but you only show one.

I recommend a correlated subquery in most databases:

```
select b.*
from b
where b.date = (select min(b2.date)
                from b b2
                where b2.group_id = b.group_id
               );
```

I see.  You need to `join` first and then use `row_number()`:

```
select ab.*
from (select a.group_id, a.id, a.subject, b.date,
             row_number() over (partition by a.group_id order by b.date) as seqnum
      from A a join
           B b
           on a.id = b.id
     ) ab
where seqnum = 1
order by date desc;
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response! unfortunately, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. But the column that you try to use to partition (ie `group_id`) comes from table `a`, which is not available in the subquery.

You would need to `JOIN` and assign the row number in a subquery, and *then* filter in the outer query.

```
select * 
from (
    select 
        a.group_id, 
        a.id, 
        a.subject, 
        b.date,
        row_number() over (partition by a.group_id order by b.date asc) as seqnum
    from a
    inner join b on ON a.id = b.id 
)
where seqnum = 1
ORDER BY date desc;
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response! unfortunately, still getting the same error.

Comment: @Fun-zin: please let me know which RDBMS (and version) you are using...

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve your goal though it may not be the efficient one

```
SELECT
  A.group_id, A.id, B.Date, A.subject
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.Id = B.Id
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    A.Group_id, MIN(B.Date) AS Date
  FROM A
  INNER JOIN B
  ON A.Id = B.Id
  GROUP BY A.group_id
) AS supportTable
ON A.group_id = supportTable.group_id
AND B.Date = supportTable.Date
```